# How do I upload .docx using Codeigniter? (PHP)

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

I'm attempting to upload a .docx using the upload helper in Codeigniter.

```
public function upload($id,$type){
        $folder = $type;
        $config['upload_path'] = RESOURCE_PATH . $folder;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf|doc|docx';
        $config['max_size'] = '100000';
        $this->CI->load->library('upload',$config);
        //$this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if (!$this->CI->upload->do_upload('userfile')){
            echo $this->CI->upload->display_errors();
        }
 ....
```

The upload function works fine on my local host. However, when I try uploading the .docx file on the server I get "The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed".

I can upload other files on the server and the code is an exact copy of what I have locally. I also googled around and found some people changed the mime for .docx to:

```
'docx'  =>  array('application/msword','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document','application/octet-stream')
```

but that doesn't seem to have resolved the issue. What could be going wrong and how do I resolve the issue so I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try to add this mime type: `application/zip` to `application/config/mimes.php` for `docx`. It works for me.
If it not help. Open `system/libraries/Upload.php`(line 205) and do this:

```
var_dump($this->file_type);
exit();
```

You will see file type of you .docx and need to add it to docx mimes list in config.

Comment: This helped me answer the question. For some reason it was seeing it as "application/x-zip". I added this to the mime type for docx and it worked.

Comment: Few weeks ago's I had a similar problem. Glad, what my desicion is helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, for my case it was displaying inode/x-empty which i added in mimes and it worked.

Comment: For me the mime type 'application/zip' was already but upload of .docx was not working. Adding 'application/msword' made it work. So it seems, one has to try it out. Yes, checking the file_type as you suggested, pretty much helps and solves the problem. Not sure if the difference is coming because of server settings

Comment: This worked for me.
array('application/msword','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document','application/octet-stream')

Comment: var_dump($this->file_type);
exit(); this help me. Thanks @jonijones

Comment: For Codeigniter 3.1.8, it will be in line no: 462

Answer (score 0):

Open the `application/config/mimes.php` file and change the mime types array of doc and docx with the following mime types.

```
'doc'  => array('application/msword', 'application/octet-stream'),
'docx' => array('application/msword', 'application/octet-stream','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'),
```

Just replace doc and docx elements value with the above mime types array.